# Can you INSERT SELECT multiple rows without running select every time for the same row?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

If I have a table and I need a value from another value and the other values are coming from somewhere else, do I have to run a select every time ?

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, otherValue) VALUES 
(SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE id = 1, outsideValue1),
(SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE id = 1, outsideValue2),
(SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE id = 1, outsideValue3);
```

So the name it's the same and the otherValue differs every time, I'm trying to insert in batches.

Comment: You might be able to use `INSERT INTO table ... SELECT`  (i.e. without the VALUES clause). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html. It's hard to make a specific recommendation without knowing more about your outside values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to put the "other values" in a derived table that you would cross join with the single source record:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, otherValue)
SELECT t2.name, v.val
FROM table2 t2
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'val1' as val
    UNION ALL SELECT 'val2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'val3'
) v
WHERE t2.id = 1
```

In MySQL 8.0.19 and above, we can use the VALUES/ROW syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name, otherValue)
SELECT t2.name, v.val
FROM table2 t2
CROSS JOIN (VALUES 
    ROW('val1'),
    ROW('val2'),
    ROW('val3')
) v(val)
WHERE t2.id = 1
```